# Spring JPA ManyToOne findByJoinColumn / findByForegignKey

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have 2 entities having OneToMany and ManyToOne cardinality:

```
Class PlanEntity{
@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="plan", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<TagEntity> tags;
.........
}


Class TagEntity{
@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="plan_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private PlanEntity plan;
.........
}
```

**Plan can have multiple Tags whereas each tag is associated with one Plan**. Here is the sample repository for the tag entity:

```
public interface TagEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TagEntity, Long>{
   @Query("Select pe from TagEntity pe where pe.plan.id in ?1")
   public List<PlanEntity> findByPlan(Long planId);
}
```

Here is the DDL for PLAN and TAG tables:

```
create table plan(
    id      int auto_increment  primary key,
    active  tinyint(1) default 1    not null
)

create table tag
(
    id      int auto_increment primary key,
    plan_id int          not null,
    k       varchar(255) not null,
    v       varchar(255) not null,
    constraint uk_t<>_plan_id_key unique (plan_id, k, v),
    constraint fk_tags_plan_id foreign key (plan_id) references plan (id)
)
```

But when running the above code, getting the following error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.repository.TagEntityRepository.findByPlan(java.lang.Long)! No property id found for type PlanEntity! Traversed path: TagEntity.plan
```

Code is compiled as per Sprig JPA. How to resolve this issue.
Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct your repo methodName from findByPlan() to findByPlanId() and remove that @Query() it should work just by using findByPlanId() method.

In case it does not work, then try making changes on the @Query line.
@Query("Select te from TagEntity te where te.plan in ?1")
Remove .id from plan.id in query

Comment: We already tried by changing the repo method name as fidByPlanId() but same error is there.

Comment: try making p capital for the plan entity in the query.

Comment: I think i got it, try removing .id from your query,

Comment: Thanks, Adarsh but I already tried these tricks and none working. I Will update this post if I found a solution.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Select pe.* from TagEntity pe where `pe.plan_id` in ?1
```

I guess plan_id was your column name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you are introducing a custom query it's better to follow query language instead. where plan.id is **plan_id** in your case.

```
    public interface TagEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TagEntity, Long>{
   @Query("Select pe from TagEntity pe where pe.plan_id like ?1", nativeQuery = true) 
     public List<PlanEntity> findByPlan(Long planId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working recreation of your code](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-69716812). All tests are passing so the issue must be somewhere else.  
Putting aside the errors that may be typos is your question

1. `public List<PlanEntity> findByPlan(Long planId);`
   You're getting a list of TagEntity, not PlanEntity.
   Change that to `List<TagEntity> findByPlanId(Long planId)`. And the @Query annotation is superfluous
2. `private List<B> tags;`  should be `private List<TagEntity> tags;`

Make sure all your tables are annotated with @Table(name="TABLE_NAME") and also annotate your columns with @Column(name="COLUMN_NAME") if they don't match the database names